# How do I set up WordPress and WooCommerce API so that I won't get CORS error when posting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to post a new product using WooCommerce API, but I get an error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v3/products
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

How do I set up WordPress and WooCommerce API correctly so that I won't get this error?

This is what I have so far:

```
    window.WooCommerce = new WooCommerceApi({   
    url: "http://localhost/wordpress",
    consumerKey: ****,   
    consumerSecret: ****,
    wpAPI: true,  
    version: "wc/v3" });
```

```
  const saveProduct = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.WooCommerce.postAsync("products", {
      name: name,
      regular_price: parseFloat(price),
      description: description
    })
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
```

WordPress .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

WordPress httpd-app.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /<none> / [L,R]

<Directory "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.4.1-0/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>


php_value memory_limit 512M



    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

    Include "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.4.1-0/apps/wordpress/conf/banner.conf"
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.4.1-0/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-admin">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "\*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS, POST"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept"
</Directory>

Include "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.4.1-0/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf"
```

I understand what the CORS error is but how do I solve it in this case?

Comment: May I know why are you using two ports?
localhost and localhost:3000?

Comment: Because they are two different servers, they can't be served on the same port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Wordpress theme's `functions.php` file, add the following action:

```php
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

Also, remove the ***backslash*** from the last directory block

```
<Directory "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.4.1-0/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-admin">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS, POST"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept"
</Directory>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything. :( It throws the same error. :(

Comment: Tried restarting Wordpress and React app, even whole Windows, nothing.

Comment: In that case I suggest to use axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios to call the REST API directly instead of using the WooCommerce API library, making sure to pass the cors headers in axios options